# Get multiple entries for parent object foreach child (this child is array) object within that parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 classes where 1 class is an array object of other class.

```
export class Certificate {
public certType: string;   
public certBeginDate: Date;
}

export class User {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
userGroup: string;
certificates: Array<Certificate>;
email: string;
username: string;
}
```

I get an object like this :

```
userdata: {
    {
     firstName: "name1",
     lastName: lname1,
     userGroup: ug1,
     certificates: {
            {
            certType: cer1;
            certBeginDate: Date1;
            },
            {
            certType: cer2;
            certBeginDate: Date2;
            }
        };
        email: email1;
        username: uname1;
    },
    {
     firstName: "name2",
     lastName: lname2,
     userGroup: ug2,
     certificates: {
            {
            certType: cer21;
            certBeginDate: Date21;
            }
        },
        email: email2;
        username: uname2;
    }
}
```

which I need to convert into :

```
userdatatoexport: {
{
firstName: "name1",
lastName: lname1,
userGroup: ug1,
certType: cer1;
certBeginDate: Date1;
email: email1;
username: uname1;
},
{
firstName: "name1",
lastName: lname1,
userGroup: ug1,
certType: cer2;
certBeginDate: Date2;
email: email1;
username: uname1;
},
{
firstName: "name2",
lastName: lname2,
userGroup: ug2,
certType: cer21;
certBeginDate: Date21;
email: email2;
username: uname2;
}
```

}

for this tried multiple ways but I am not able to concatenate the users object with the certificates in a proper way. the object I need to pass to export it out.

```
let a1:any[];
    this.state.userdata.map((user, index) => user.certificates.length !== 0 ? (user.certificates.map((cer, index) => a1.push({ user + cer })) ) :a1.push(user));
```

In this above solution I am getting error while push(user + cer). when I hover over the user in that it is showing (property)user as :number type it actually should be of :User type.

I need to create multiple entries for users data based on the certificates count with individual certificates data merged with the respective user data.

Edit 1 :

Using FlatMap() is resolving the issue but flatmap() is not supported on IE and Edge. So I tried to implement the logic behind the flatmap() using Map() and reduce() functions.

```
let res1 = UserData.map(User => {
        return User.certificates.length !== 0 ? User.certificates.map(cer => {
            let o = Object.assign({}, User, cer);  return o;
        }) : Object.assign({}, User, new Certificate())     
    })
```

In res1 I am getting an array of arrays of type [User & Certificate]. I just need to convert that into simple array of type [User & Certificate]. For I tried to user reducer() with concat() as :`res1.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);`
this statement works fine in the console log when I tried to debug the code.
but this statement is throwing compile errors as "concat() is not available on acc."

How can I convert :
`[[(user1 & cert11),(user1 & cert12)],[(user2 & cert1)], (user3 & cert3)]` to

```
[(user1 & cert11),(user1 & cert12),(user2 & cert1), (user3 & cert3) ].
```

Comment: Your user data is invalid is userdata and certificates supposed to be an array or object literal?

Comment: they are supposed to be array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap`

```js
var userdata = [
    {
     firstName: "name1",
     certificates: [
            {
            certType: 'a'
            },
            {
            certType: 'b'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
     firstName: "name2",
     certificates: [
            {
            certType: 'c'
            }
        ],
    }
];
let res = userdata.flatMap(user=>{
    return user.certificates.map(cert=>{
        let o = Object.assign({}, user, cert);
        delete o.certificates;
        return o;
    })
})
console.log('got ', JSON.stringify(res,null,1))
```

---

As noted by HMR, by destructuring we get to the same result as well

```js
var userdata = [
    {
     firstName: "name1",
     certificates: [
            {
            certType: 'a'
            },
            {
            certType: 'b'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
     firstName: "name2",
     certificates: [
            {
            certType: 'c'
            }
        ],
    }
];
let res = userdata.flatMap(({certificates,...user})=>{
    return certificates.map(cert=>{
        return {...cert, ...user};
    })
})
console.log('got ', JSON.stringify(res,null,1))
```

Comment: Since you use flatMap you can also use desctruring arguments: `userdata.flatMap(({ certificates, ...user }) => {
  return certificates.map(cert => ({
    ...user,
    ...cert,
  }));
});`

Comment: thx for that alternative way @HMR . Edited post accordingly. I am not familiar (yet) to that construct but this avoids the need to call delete !

Comment: You can find more information on destructuring [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/es-next-beyond/ch2.md#destructuring)

Comment: @user753642 Hi how can I do that without flatmap() as it is not supported by edge and IE.
I tried this based on flatmap logic but is have build errors
      
res2.reduce((acc, val:any) => acc.concat(val), []);
getting res2 from 

let res2 = this.state.UserData.map(User => {
            return User.certificates.length !== 0 ? User.certificates.map(cer => {
                let o = Object.assign({}, User, cer);  return o;
            }) :  Object.assign({}, User, User.certificates)     
        })
need the check for null as well for certificates array.

Comment: @Amey this is cryptic to read, you may rather update your post specifying you want a code IE compatible (with your formatted attempt)